# Error while installing pyHWM2014 with pip:

Tags: python, pip

````
  pip install pyHWM2014
    Collecting pyHWM2014
      Using cached pyhwm2014-1.1.tar.gz (18 kB)
      Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
      Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
    Requirement already satisfied: timeutil in c:\users\naci_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pyHWM2014) (2.1.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\naci_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from timeutil->pyHWM2014) (1.19.2)
    Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.Requirement already satisfied: nose in c:\users\naci_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from timeutil->pyHWM2014) (1.3.7)
    Building wheels for collected packages: pyHWM2014
      Building wheel for pyHWM2014 (setup.py): started
    
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
      python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
      exit code: 1
      
      [73 lines of output]
      
      CommandNotFoundError: No command 'conda nose'.
      
      WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
      Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
      To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
      C:\Users\naci_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      Requirement already satisfied: timeutil in c:\users\naci_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2.1.0)
      Requirement already satisfied: nose in c:\users\naci_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from timeutil) (1.3.7)
      Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\naci_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from timeutil) (1.19.2)
      C:\Users\naci_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running config_cc
      unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
      running config_fc
      unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
      running build_src
      build_src  Building wheel for pyHWM2014 (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
      Running setup.py clean for pyHWM2014
    Failed to build pyHWM2014
    Installing collected packages: pyHWM2014
      Running setup.py install for pyHWM2014: started
      Running setup.py install for pyHWM2014: finished with status 'error'
    ```
      building extension "hwm14" sources
      f2py options: ['--quiet']
        adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.8\build\src.win-amd64-3.8\fortranobject.c' to sources.
        adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.8\build\src.win-amd64-3.8' to include_dirs.
        adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.8\hwm14-f2pywrappers.f' to sources.
        adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.8\hwm14-f2pywrappers2.f90' to sources.
      building data_files sources
      build_src: building npy-pkg config files
      C:\Users\naci_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build_py
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\pyhwm2014
      copying pyhwm2014\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\pyhwm2014
      running build_ext
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
      customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
      get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
      customize GnuFCompiler
      Could not locate executable g77
      Could not locate executable f77
      customize IntelVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable ifort
      Could not locate executable ifl
      customize AbsoftFCompiler
      Could not locate executable f90
      customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable DF
      customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable efl
      customize Gnu95FCompiler
      Could not locate executable gfortran
      Could not locate executable f95
      customize G95FCompiler
      Could not locate executable g95
      customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
      customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
      Could not locate executable efort
      Could not locate executable efc
      customize PGroupFlangCompiler
      Could not locate executable flang
      don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
      warning: build_ext: f77_compiler=None is not available.
      
      building 'hwm14' extension
      error: extension 'hwm14' has Fortran sources but no Fortran compiler found
      Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\naci_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 59, in closed
          return stream.closed
      ValueError: underlying buffer has been detached
      [end of output]
      
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyHWM2014
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
      Running setup.py install for pyHWM2014 did not run successfully.
      exit code: 1
      
      [73 lines of output]
      
      CommandNotFoundError: No command 'conda nose'.
      
      WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
      Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
      To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
      C:\Users\naci_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      Requirement already satisfied: timeutil in c:\users\naci_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2.1.0)
      Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\naci_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from timeutil) (1.19.2)
      Requirement already satisfied: nose in c:\users\naci_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from timeutil) (1.3.7)
      C:\Users\naci_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running install
      C:\Users\naci_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running config_cc
      unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
      running config_fc
      unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
      running build_src
      build_src
      building extension "hwm14" sources
      f2py options: ['--quiet']
        adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.8\build\src.win-amd64-3.8\fortranobject.c' to sources.
        adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.8\build\src.win-amd64-3.8' to include_dirs.
        adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.8\hwm14-f2pywrappers.f' to sources.
        adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.8\hwm14-f2pywrappers2.f90' to sources.
      building data_files sources
      build_src: building npy-pkg config files
      running build_py
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\pyhwm2014
      copying pyhwm2014\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\pyhwm2014
      running build_ext
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
      customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
      get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
      customize GnuFCompiler
      Could not locate executable g77
      Could not locate executable f77
      customize IntelVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable ifort
      Could not locate executable ifl
      customize AbsoftFCompiler
      Could not locate executable f90
      customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable DF
      customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable efl
      customize Gnu95FCompiler
      Could not locate executable gfortran
      Could not locate executable f95
      customize G95FCompiler
      Could not locate executable g95
      customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
      customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
      Could not locate executable efort
      Could not locate executable efc
      customize PGroupFlangCompiler
      Could not locate executable flang
      don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
      warning: build_ext: f77_compiler=None is not available.
      
      building 'hwm14' extension
      error: extension 'hwm14' has Fortran sources but no Fortran compiler found
      Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\naci_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 59, in closed
          return stream.closed
      ValueError: underlying buffer has been detached
      [end of output]
      
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    error: legacy-install-failure
    
    Encountered error while trying to install package.
    
    pyHWM2014
    
    note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
    hint: See above for output from the failure.
````

Comment: What OS are you using? Windows?

Comment: Yes I am using Windows 10 64bit

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @NurTepedelen I'm unable to recreate the Error and I'm really interested in it. Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0):

> don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
> warning: build_ext: f77_compiler=None is not available.

Means you don't have a fortran compiler installed. Try to install `gfortran`.

##### Step 1

Install [MSYSY2](https://www.msys2.org/)

##### Step 2

Invoke Msys2 window. The program runs automatically for the first time. After that, search for "msys2" in the search menu. Choose MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit

##### Step 3

Msys2 consists of many dependent programs. Each program is prepared as a package. If the package is modified, you can download it through the internet. This process is automated by a command `pacman`.

For the first time, you have to date the built-in packages through the internet. In the Msys2 windows, type the following command.

`pacman -Syu`

##### Step 4

GFortran is also provided as a package. Type the following command in the window to install GFortran.

`pacman -Su gcc-fortran`

As above, it will ask you if you want to install the package. Type `y`, and wait for a while to finish the installation. After this step, you can use GFortran in this window.

##### Step 5

To be able to use `gfortran` in your normal command prompt you need to add the following directories to your `PATH` environment variable.

`C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`, `C:\msys64\usr\bin`

To add anything to your PATH in Windows 10:

1. Search “Advanced System Settings” in the search bar
2. Open the “environment variables” window, click on the PATH variable and click on “Edit”
3. Click on the “New” button and add the 2 directories to your PATH
4. Click on OK on all the windows and open a new Command Window and you will be able to use `gfortran` into your windows command prompt!

You can confirm the successful installation with the following command in your normal command prompt.

`gfortran --version`

###### You may also have to install or update `conda` to make it work.

Download and install [here](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html)

If you have it installed already try updating it.
If you have it added to PATH already just run `conda update conda`. Else open "Anaconda Prompt" from your search menu and run the same command.

Restart all command prompt windows and try

`pip install pyHWM2014`

again it may work now.